# WPF How to get values from stackpanel inside a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently developing a WPF application that contains a `ListBox` and inside it a `ListBoxItem` Within a `StackPanel` and one `Image` and `Label` inside `StackPanel`. All ListBoxItem are generated through database values and displayed inside `ListBox` control. But when user select one `ListBoxItem` how to get a value from a `Label` for example? This is my XAML code:

```
<ListBox Name="LIstBProdutos"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="336"
         Margin="39,98,0,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="358">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                       Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

**Code Behind Method**

```
private void BTTProduct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    ListProd.Items.Clear();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string consulta = "";
    if (CCKBOXFilterProdCat.IsChecked == true)
    {
        var idCategoria = Int32.Parse(((DataRowView)CBBFilterCatProd.SelectedItem)["id"].ToString());
        consulta = "and categoria ='" + idCategoria + "'";
    }
    c.ConsultaSql("select * from produto where nome like '%" + TBXNomeProduto.Text + "%'" + "" + consulta + " ");
    c.NonQuery();
    c.DataSet();
    reader = c.cm.ExecuteReader();
    int nome = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < c.ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; a++)
    {
        nome = nome+1;
        ListBoxItem lbi = new ListBoxItem();
        lbi.Width = 100;
        lbi.Height = 152;
        Image img = new Image();
        StackPanel stp = new StackPanel();
        Label lbl = new Label();
        Label lbl2 = new Label();
        stp.Name = "Stack"+ nome.ToString();
        reader.Read();
        string IdImagem = reader["id"].ToString();
        lbl.Content = reader["nome"].ToString();
        lbl2.Content = "R$ " + reader["preco"].ToString();              
        var pa = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "produtos/");
        var uri = new Uri(pa + IdImagem + ".jpg");
        BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(uri);
        img.Source = bm;
        stp.Children.Add(img);
        stp.Children.Add(lbl);
        stp.Children.Add(lbl2);
        stp.ToolTip = reader["nome"].ToString() + "\n Somente R$ " + reader["preco"].ToString();
        lbi.Content = stp;                
        ListProd.Items.Add(lbi);                
    }
}
```

How to get the value from `ListBoxItem`?

Comment: [The problem goes away if you had used _databinding_ in the first place](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx)

Comment: Now I create a following Method: `if (LIstBProdutos.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                ListBoxItem lbi = LIstBProdutos.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
                StackPanel sp = lbi.Content as StackPanel;
                foreach (UIElement ui in sp.Children)
                {
                    if (ui is Label)
                    {
                        
                        MessageBox.Show("" + ui);
                        
                    }
                }` But I have two label,  and I need to get only first label.

Answer (score 1):

You can do probably do something like this

You can create a class with your Database Fields you are fetching

```
public class DbRecord
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string preco { get; set; }
}
```

Now after checking whether any record is selected in the ListBox you can create the object of the Class we have created and then fetching the Record.

```
if (ListProd.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    DbRecord Record = new DbRecord();
    Record = (ListProd.SelectedItem) as DbRecord;
    string nome = Record.nome;
    string preco = Record.preco;
}
```

You have the values of both the labels in the variables.